# MySQL Stored Procedure CREATE Error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have about 2 years of mySQL under my belt but am diving into stored procedures for the first time to create an internal analytic tool for my site. I am usually good at tracking down SQL errors but this one is eluding me.

The error I get is this :

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

This is the code I execute to receive this error:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE STORE_ANALYTICS (IN chain VARCHAR(300))
BEGIN
    UPDATE _analytics_clicks 
    SET chainCount = (chainCount + 1) 
    WHERE visitChain = chain;

    IF SELECT ROW_COUNT() = 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO _analytics_clicks (visitChain, chainCount) 
        VALUES (chain, 1);
    END IF;
END|
```

It is worth noting that before I execute this, I executed

```
DELIMITER |
```

The structure of the table I am trying to alter is this:

```
chainID int(11)        auto_increment
visitChain  varchar(300)    
chainCount  int(11)
```

When I execute line 3 by itself, replacing visitChain=chain with visitChain='0' (0 is a test chain i enetered), the command runs fine and chainCount is incremented.

Any ideas on why I am getting this error/the stored procedure is not being created?

Thanks,
Matt

EDIT :

Included delimiter in SQL command:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE STORE_ANALYTICS (IN chain VARCHAR(300))
BEGIN
UPDATE _analytics_clicks SET chainCount = (chainCount+1) WHERE visitChain=chain;
IF ROW_COUNT() = 0 THEN
INSERT INTO _analytics_clicks (visitChain, chainCount) VALUES (chain, 1);
END IF;
END|
DELIMITER ;
```

Gave me this error:
    Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.2.0.1\libraries\import\sql.php on line 119

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
IF ROW_COUNT() = 0 THEN
```

rather than `IF SELECT ROW_COUNT() = 0 THEN`. No need for the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your delimiter is not being set properly.

I usually include the delimiter set/unset statements *with* my SQL source, that way "it just runs" - it's good practice that every SQL file can run stand-alone eg:

```
delimiter ~

create procedure ...

end;~

delimiter ;
```

Try changing your delimiter to something less deadly than a pipe char - try my tilda `~` char, which never gives me any trouble. I've seen `$$` used often as well.

Comment: edited original post as code gets all messed up when i post it here, but adding the delimiter into the SQL statment made it freeze.

Comment: How are you submitting this to mysql? Maybe that pipe is getting in the way - is the command line parsing as an actual pipe? Try pasting the contents of your file directly in the mysql command line client.

Comment: i am using php myadmin, i will try a different delim, but i dont think that would be an issue. Changed Delim, still same issue as my last edit. Hmmm